# How to install package file to virtualenv folder?

Tags: virtualenv, python-venv

I need to install python packages into a virtualenv. The virtualenv is placed on a ramdisk, and I want the actual files to be installed in the virtualenv folder so that I can benefit from the the lower latency when loading.

It is not clear to me from the documentation I have seen if the package files are downloaded (or imported from global) to the virtualevn folder, or stored globally with only a reference to the version in the virtualenv (ambiguity on import/access).

Which is default behaviour by virtualenv? I can not see the size of the venv folder increasing as I install packages.

- Folder size before installing pandas, numpy, scikit, tesorflow,
  keras: *4k*
- Folder size after: *4k*

If importing the package files is not default behaviour, how can I install packages to the virtualenv folder and set the interpreter to load the installed packages from the folder?

Comment: To install packages to a virtualenv you have to activate the virtualenv. Or use its `pip` instead of global `pip`. Either `source env/bin/activate && pip install` or `env/bin/pip install`.

Comment: Yes, I am activating the venv. `source ./bin/activate` `which pip3` returns */venv_folder/bin/pip3* `pip3 install pandas numpy ...`

Comment: `pip3 show --files pandas numpy`